# Is there an other solution than copy-only full backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I do a full backup once a month and then incremental backups in between.

But meanwhile another users could do full backup and that break my chain. I know that there is a full back up with copy only.

But in my case I can't know when and who will do the backup, so I need to find a solution to implement on my side to avoid this problem.

Does someone have an idea or a solution to implement? Thank you very much.

Comment: Should the other users have permission to take backups? Especially, if they are breaking the chain by not ticking the copy_only option.

Comment: I suggest that your organization control who can perform backups more strictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sample is a bit on the verbose side to make it easier to understand, but the table msdb.dbo.backupset can help you with this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupset-transact-sql

```
declare @MostRecentAuthorizedFullBackup datetime
declare @MostRecentUnauthorizedNonCopyOnlyBackup datetime
declare @AuthorizedBackupUser nvarchar(128) = N'YourBackupUser'
declare @DatabaseName nvarchar(128) = N'YourDatabase'

select @MostRecentAuthorizedFullBackup = backup_start_date
from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name = @DatabaseName
  and is_copy_only = 0
  and type = 'D'
  and user_name = @AuthorizedBackupUser
order by backup_start_date desc

select @MostRecentUnauthorizedNonCopyOnlyBackup = backup_start_date
from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name = @DatabaseName
  and is_copy_only = 0
  and type = 'D'
  and user_name <> @AuthorizedBackupUser
order by backup_start_date desc

if @MostRecentAuthorizedFullBackup > @MostRecentUnauthorizedNonCopyOnlyBackup
begin
    print 'Differential base is good'
end
else
begin
    print 'Differential base is bad'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But my question was not about knowing if the the chain is broke and if a the differential base is bad.   I want to know if there is a solution that I can implemet that whatever and whenever somewhere does a full backup that will not affect my differential ?

Comment: The answer to that is no.  The only way to avoid the broken differential base is to limit the other backups to copy only, and there is no way to enforce that without blocking their ability to do backups at all.  You can add conditional logic to your backup so that it will revert to a full backup if the differential base is broken due to someone else taking a non-copy only backup.